# Finding rational points on a non-trivial algebraic curve

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The curve in question is defined as the set of all points $(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are in $(0,1)$, and that satisfy the following:

$$ \left( x^4 - 6 x^2 + 1 \right)  \left( y^4-6y^2+1
 \right) -64 x^2 y^2 = 0$$

I do not know how I could identify even a single rational point on this curve, let alone others.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes... sorry, I have edited it to correct that mistake.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: May I ask where this problem comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation
$$ 
\left( x^4-6x^2+1 \right)  \left( y^4-6y^2+1 \right) - 64 x^2 y^2 = 0
$$
has no rational solutions; indeed the only solutions for which both
$X := x^2$ and $Y := y^2$ are rational are those with $x^2 = y^2 = -1$.

**Bruno Joyal** already noted that $X$ and $Y$ satisfy
$$ 
\left( X^2 - 6X + 1 \right) \left( Y^2 - 6Y + 1 \right) - 64 X Y = 0,
$$
and noted that this equation still has degree $4$ and that
in general a degree-$4$ curve has genus $3$.  The good news is that
in fact this curve has genus $0$.  The bad news is that it is not 
a rational curve over $\bf Q$, and the only rational solution
is the singularity at $(X,Y) = (-1,-1)$.

For the "good news", note that the curve has degree $2$ in each variable
separately, which makes its genus at most $1$; the node at $(-1,-1)$
then drops the genus to zero.

For the "bad news", compute the discriminant with respect to $Y$,
finding that $8 (X+1)^2 (X^2+10X+1)$ must be a square.  If $X=-1$ then
the equation $(X^2 - 6X + 1) (Y^2 - 6Y + 1) - 64 X Y = 0$ becomes
$8(Y+1)^2 = 0$, so we recover $(X,Y) = (-1,-1)$.
If $X \neq -1$ then $2(X^2 + 10 X + 1)$ must be a square.  But 
$2(X^2 + 10 X + 1) = 2 (X+5)^2 - 3 \cdot 4^2$, and
$2a^2 - 3b^2$ cannot be a square unless $a=b=0$,
because $2$ is not a square mod $3$.
[We could also show this using congruences modulo $8$.]
Hence $(-1,-1)$ is the unique rational solution of
$(X^2 - 6X + 1) (Y^2 - 6Y + 1) = 64 X Y$, and we're done.

Answer (score 4):

First, you might want to try finding a rational point on

$$(X^2-6X+1)(Y^2-6Y+1) = 64XY.$$

It is an easier problem. Then you can try to find a point $(X_0, Y_0)$ for which both $X_0$ and $Y_0$ are squares.

The projective closure $X \subseteq \mathbf P^2$ of the curve $(X^2-6X+1)(Y^2-6Y+1) = 64XY$ is a plane curve of degree $4$. The first thing you should do is check whether it is smooth. I didn't check.

If it is smooth, then it has genus $(4-1)(4-2)/2 = 3$, and Faltings' theorem implies that there are **finitely many** rational points on $X$. It's very hard to know *a priori* how many points there are, so if you do a brute force search for points, you might not be able to tell when you have found all of the points.

If $X$ is not smooth, compute the normalization $\widetilde X \to X$. (You can do this completely mechanically, by blowing up at the singularities until they resolve. This is a nice thing with curves that doesn't work in higher dimensions.) Then try to find a rational point on $\widetilde X$. Whether there is much hope will ultimately depend on the genus $g$ of $\widetilde X$. If $g=0$ then you will be able to parametrize $X$ using rational functions (over $\overline{\mathbf Q})$. If $g=1$ then $\widetilde{X}$ becomes an elliptic curve after a finite base change and a choice of point (over the new base). In this case, there are algorithms to compute a basis for the group of points. If $g>1$, you'll have to be creative.

Finding rational points on algebraic varieties is, in general, a very difficult problem with no straightforward solution.

Comment: No trivial rational points seem to be on that curve either....  

I realize that no general solution exists for finding rational points on arbitrary curves of higher degree, but I was rather hoping that there might be a definable way to find them for a specific curve.

What I'm taking from your response, however, is that no mechanism exists for finding such points, even for specific curves, and in fact, the only way they can be found is by luck if no trivial or otherwise obvious candidates can be identified.

Comment: BTW it's Faltings' theorem, not "Falting's", because his name is Gerd Faltings.  But it turns out that the curve actually has genus zero but is not rational over $\bf Q$.

Comment: Dear @Noam: Thanks for pointing that out. Honest typo!

Comment: You're welcome.  No problem.